# PHP preg_split utf8 characters

Tags: php, cakephp, preg-split

Have problem with preg split and utf. This is code:

```
$original['words'] = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $original['text']);
print_r($original);
```

This is answer:

```
Array
(

    [text] => Šios baterijos kaista
    [words] => Array
        (
            [0] => �
            [1] => ios
            [2] => baterijos
            [3] => kaista
```

This code is runing in CakePHP framework. Make a notice that [text] is showed correctly before words and is messed in split progress. By the way, I tried using these one:

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8'); 
mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8');  
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
```

None helped. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php ?

Answer (score 19):

You need to enable utf-8 mode for `preg_split` by adding the `u` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the regular expression:

```
preg_split("/[\s]+/u", $original['text']);
```

The configuration directives you mention as part of trying to find a solution play no role here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$original = mb_split("[\s]+", 'Šios baterijos kaista');
print_r($original);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Šios
    [1] => baterijos
    [2] => kaista
)
```

Note:

1) Don't forget to remove the leading and trailing '/' from the regex pattern when using [mb_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

2) Only works if the [mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) extension is enabled.